# How to configure multiple web site with IIS 7?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7

I'm trying to configure a second website on my IIS. The first one is working well on port 80.
I don't need any DNS, so i'm accessing it with http://public_ip_address and that's it.

I created a new website, give it the port 8080, the folder path.
Locally it works when I try http://localhost:8080 but when from the outside I try http://public_ip_address:8080, nothing respond.

I enabled Anonymous Authentication, but still nothing.

What am I missing ?

Thx for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you forgot top allow the port on the **Windows Server firewall**. Add TCP port 8080 as allowed protocol. By default Windows Server 2008 doesn't allow connections to that port.

Comment: Ho yeah that was it... so simple that I didn't even try because I saw that there already was a rules for HTTP, I thought I would let any http goes in... Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

If your web server is sitting behind a firewall or other gateway device then you need to make sure you're passing HTTP traffic through on the gateway for port 8080.

If your web server itself is public facing then make sure that your site listening on port 8080 is bound to the public IP address and that your default web site is not bound to that address.

Comment: The server has a public ip address so no firewall or something before it.
What exactly do I have to do on IIS ? Both my Default web site and my second website is bound with ip address * but with different port, so when it try to access with http ://public_ip_address:port_ number I can access the website I want depending on the port_number. No ?

Comment: @Bastien: yeah, you're right.  I had the host header thing stuck in my head.  So long as your firewall's passing through on port 8080 your IIS config should be good.  But you already know that :)